# Rendering Highcharts Chart in Multiple divs with same ID

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I was wondering if it was possible to render the same chart to multiple divs with the same ID.  I am just using this as a template to show how this stuff functions, ultimately, i'll tie into this and dynamically create the divs on the fly and can have unique IDs for each of them, but rather than just copy/paste the chart code 4 times i'd like the same chart to render in each of the divs.  I've tried using the .each() function but it still only renders in the first div.

Here is a fiddle rather than copy/paste all of that code and a short snippet of the each function; http://jsfiddle.net/Chmts/58/

```
$(function () {
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#CampaignPercent').each(function(){
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: this,
                type: 'bar',
                width: 200,
                margin: [0,0,0,0]
            },
```

Comment: ids have to be unique, if you have multiple elements with the same id, only the first element is normally found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs should be always unique, `$('#CampaignPercent')` will only return first element with id  `CampaignPercent`. you should rather use common classname(say `CampaignPercent`) and then use class selector `.` to target all the elements:

```
 $('.CampaignPercent').each(function(){
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: this,
            type: 'bar',
            width: 200,
            margin: [0,0,0,0]
        },
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gk46q3md/)**

Comment: well jeez that worked perfect, i honestly was messing with that too in a fiddle and couldn't get it to render, but i'm running with ya here, i'll make as answered whenever i get the chance to, have to wait 9 more minutes lol thank you