# Highcharts - use same chart on multiple places

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a website where the same solid gauge graph has to be used on multiple places at the same time, however I'd like to be able to update them all by simply calling a single line of code:

```
section1_graph.series[0].setData([32], true);
```

So really 1 instance, but multiple renders.

Who can help me? ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering Highcharts Chart in Multiple divs with same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921507/rendering-highcharts-chart-in-multiple-divs-with-same-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example how to add multiple charts with the same options and simple updating. To add more charts, just add `div` element with `gaugeContainer` class.

```
var options = {
    series: [{
        type: 'gauge'
    }],
    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200
    }
}

var containers = document.getElementsByClassName('gaugeContainer');

for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    Highcharts.chart(containers[i], options);
}

function setChartsData(data) {
    Highcharts.charts.forEach(function(chart) {
        if (chart && chart.renderTo.classList.contains("gaugeContainer")) {
            chart.series[0].setData(data.slice());
        }
    });
}

setChartsData([32]);

setTimeout(function() {
    setChartsData([120]);
}, 1500);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6qxtd20g/